# Adding offline search to static websites created by website generators for internal use in company

Tags: algolia, docusaurus

I am exploring ways for adding offline search in Docusaurus in any of versions v1 or v2.

The solution mentioned at https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/search/ by using Algolia DocSearch. But problem is "Note that your website needs to be publicly available for this to work (i.e., not behind a firewall). The service is free".

No company wants their confidential information to make public. What are the different cleaner and easier options we have to enable local search.

Has anyone tried: Flexsearch
https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch

I am aware that discussion is going at https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/776

https://github.com/facebook/Docusaurus/issues/789

Tweet: https://twitter.com/docusaurus/status/1009453481017524224

But I am not able to make anything out of it that which offline search works fine with docusaurus.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for some offline search plugins under our [community plugins section](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/next/resources#community-plugins). They are not officially endorsed but some of them work pretty well.